# Lottie icon will not show up HTML

Tags: html, css, lottie

I have a lottie icon (https://app.lottiefiles.com/animation/4b8e60d4-3950-437a-af55-535c836a79c3) that for some reason will not show up. I put the  tag in the head and the icon styling in the body. Can anyone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src=“https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js”></script>
</head>
<body>
        <lottie-player src=“https://lottie.host/b35cc63e-e72a-4978-add6-d71a6cbcfdab/SQ1XbCeUpR.json” background=“#ffffff” speed=“1” style=“width: 300px; height: 300px” loop controls autoplay direction=“1” mode=“normal”></lottie-player>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</html>
```

I tried putting the links in different places on the document.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the `“...”` quotes used in their 'Embed HTML'.

Instead of using the standard quotes (`'...'` or `"..."`), they use `“...”` which doesn't function in the same manner as standard quotes.

All you need to do is to replace the `“...”` quotes with `'...'` or `"..."`.

**Note :** for best practice, scripts should be placed just before the `</body>`, not in the `<head>...</head>` nor after the `</body>` tag, scripts that should be placed in the `<head>` are either analytics tracking scripts or asyncronouse loading scripts.

This should work just fine :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <lottie-player src="https://lottie.host/b35cc63e-e72a-4978-add6-d71a6cbcfdab/SQ1XbCeUpR.json" background="#ffffff" speed="1" style="width: 300px; height: 300px" loop controls autoplay direction="1" mode="normal"></lottie-player>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```